# How can i share 2 differents types with only one share intent?

Tags: android, share

In my app there's a share button that calls this method:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
String audioClipFileName="bell.mp3";
sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.gruchka.guessthesound/" + R.raw.bell));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Get help with:"));
```

This button shares the audio file: 'bell.mp3'. 
I want this button to also share the text below the audio file. 
How can i solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this below setType line:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR_TEXT");
```

Only would works in apps that support it.

Comment: i worte to youi in the other question: This is what i did but the intent type is audio/mp3 and it is need to be something else

Comment: No matter, only add this line below setType line